# Accessing logs of a node js code running as a server

Tags: node.js, linux, process, stdout, stderr

There is a node js code running on a linux server as a process. 
I have the process id of the process using

```
 ps -aef | grep node
```

which gives

```
amit 20897     1  0 Sep26 ?        03:07:06 node energyMonitor/newBroker.js
```

I want to access the stdout,stderr of this process, to view the what `console.log()` statements are priniting. I tried with

```
tail -f /proc/20897/fd/1
```

but of no use, can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: How you are running your node application??

Comment: This application is already up and running, I'm afraid that I'm not sure of it

Comment: to know how the application is running why you are afraid? Whether you are running by `pm2` or  `forever` or some other, so that you can see the logs accordingly

Comment: The op means he doesn't know.

Comment: @tbking what is op???

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/op/ @Subburaj

Comment: @Subburaj , I think its by `pm2` . How can we see the logs ?

Comment: @cvg then simply do `pm2 logs`

Comment: No, that is not giving me logs, so may be its not running by pm2. :( ,is there a way we can find out how the process is running ?

Comment: Is there a way to collect logs if I just run it as node file.js ?